# Django Plotly Dash Scatter chart loses interactivity when DataTable added

Tags: css, django, plotly, plotly-dash

I am using the [django-plotly-dash](https://django-plotly-dash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) utility to embed Dash apps into a Django page.

If I have a [Plotly Scatter](https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/) chart on the same app as a [Dash DataTable](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable) then the chart loses it's interactivity.

Comment: BTW - I didn't elaborate on the question because I already had the answer which fill sin the required level of detail. See below.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the culprit was a Dash styling css from [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP).

I previously had it included externally via

```
external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = DjangoDash("signalapp" external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
```

And switched it to local hosting by changing to

```
app.css.append_css({ "external_url" : "/static/myapp/css/bWLwgP.css" })
```

Then by a process of elimination discovered that the float parameter of the following class caused the issue if set to either 'right' or 'left'

```
.columns {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
```